# how do i use proxy with electron-fetch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am using  [electron-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-fetch)  npm and I want to use a proxy with it. I tried the `proxy` option which works in `request` npm yet it seems to not work.

this is my code block, yet i see my ip always the same(proxy not used). for demonstration i put the proxy ip as `1.1.1.1`

my proxy doesn't have any authentication so i don't have to use `user` or `password` options like it shows in the link, yet if somebody gives an answer it'd also be nice to see an example of that.

```
const fetch = require('electron-fetch').default

fetch("https://api.ipify.org/?format=text" , {proxy  : 'http://1.1.1.1'})
    .then(res => res.text())
.then(body => console.log(body))
```

this doesn't connect to the proxy